# Attributes on Shopping Cart - Magento

Tags: magento

My question is simple. I basically have 2 attributes on which my simple products are attached to my config items.

I want to display the 2  attributes which are COLOR and SIZE in the shopping cart which will be of simple items.

How can I do that?

I am using Magento 1.5 and Single Configurable Product ext is also installed.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to the Admin section, select products->Attributes->Manage Attributes.

Then just click on "Add New Attribute" on the top right hand side.

Once you have added it, clear the magento cache, and edit a product.

You will see the attribute in the General tab being available for editing.

ensure you enable it for the Front End too, to display it.

The use code like below in the template that displays the item:

```
<?php $_item = $this->getItem()?>
<?php $_product= Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId()) ?>
<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
```

Comment: Hello Shaun, You didn't read my question. I didn't ask how to add attributes. I said I want to display attributes on my shopping cart.